# Playing audio file from directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have Gridview when i click play it will play audio file it will get directory from database and play the audio by opening windows media player it working fine in visual studio i am using System.Diagnostics.Process in my code.I hosted application in IIS where OS is Windows 7 when i try to play its not opening windows media player and not playing audio file.

I had seen suggestions in Internet where i need to give permission to IIS admin Service to interact with desktop applications but i hadn't seen any IIS admin Service in Services.msc.

Any one can suggest me

Comment: Are you really trying to play music on user PC using server side proces of WMP? Question to trash cuz you dont understand web dev

Comment: Wow, the first sentence is so long!

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript or Flash (ugh) on the website to play audio on a web page. It's only by virtue of the fact that your development environment has your webserver running on your desktop that you can play audio from the webserver directly.

Comment: @J.Doe: that's kind of a mean thing to say. The person doesn't understand some facet of web development. You need to explain why instead of trashing them for being "stupid".

Comment: @siride No, he dont need JS or Flash, can do it by HTML only (`<audio>` tag)

Comment: @J.Doe: it seems a bit dynamic (Gridview), so I don't know if a static audio tag will work. That's why I suggested JS.

Comment: @siride So just put in `src` link without `atutoplay` attribute

Comment: @siride I had used HTML tags but if audio is in application directory it will play otherwise it won't

Comment: @kallaparijoseph: it needs to be sent to the client. You cannot play from the webserver, period.

Comment: @siride if possible can you make me understandable using a small example

Comment: @siride how to integrate a windows media player in asp.net

Comment: @kallaparijoseph: you don't need to integrate windows media player. The web browser is able to play audio using audio tags. You just need to make sure that the audio file is downloadable. You don't need to do any other integration.

Comment: @siride Thanq for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling a desktop application, you can use javascript or the HTML audio tag.

There's a js library called Howler (https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/), it makes easier to play audio from the browser.

In your gridview, you can have a column that has a button to play the audio, this button has an attribute that contains the audio path

Something like this:

```
<button data-audiosrc="pathtoaudio.mp3">Play audio</button>
```

Then you use this tag to call the howler to play the audio.
This is one approach.

Another one is to publish these files to an IIS web application and you can call it by the browser http://AudioIISApp/youraudio.mp3 (for example), will open another tab, so the user can listen or download.

This second is more easy and faster to implement!

Comment: I had used HTML tag but it will play audio if it is application directory otherwise it wont play.I have case where i want to play audio from any directory in asp.net

Comment: For the user play on the browser, as far as I know, the files must be stored on an IIS application. what you can do is, instead play on browser, make your apllication download the file. This way, you can find your file anywhere you want.

Edit: You can even have in your database table, a column for the file URL, to play a preview of the audio on the browser, and another column with the server physical path.

Comment: My case is i have directory of audio file in the column.When i click play button it has to go to that directory and play audio file.When i am using visual studio it will play but when i hosted in IIS it not at all playing audio

Comment: Try creating an user to run the apppool for your application and give the permissions to read to your folder and give it a try! :)

Comment: how to integrate windows media player in asp.net